# Trying to hide some Twitter API credentials in a Yaml file, getting uninitialized constant EnvironmentVariables::Application::YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, yaml

I have an initializer `environment_variables.rb` :

```
module EnvironmentVariables
    class Application < Rails::Application
        config.before_configuration do
            env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'environment_variables.yml').to_s

            if File.exists?(env_file)
                YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
                    ENV[key.to_s] = value
                end # end YAML.load_file
            end # end if File.exists?
        end # end config.before_configuration
    end # end class
end
```

Which is I've checked is finding a file called `environment_variables.yml`in config:

```
test:
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: ""
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: ""
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: ""
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ""
development:
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: ""
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: ""
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: ""
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ""
production:
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "" 
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "" 
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: ""
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ""
```

However I get an error when trying to run my code:

```
class TwitterAPI
    def client
        @client ||= Twitter.REST.Client.new do |config|
            config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
            config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
            config.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
            config.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
        end 
    end
end
```

By making a call in a spec puts `TwitterAPI.new.client` to test it. The error looks like this:

```
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/TakeStock/stock/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:7:in `block in <class:Application>': uninitialized constant EnvironmentVariables::Application::YAML (NameError)
```

Any suggestions as to the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you `require 'yaml'` anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uninitialized constant EnvironmentVariables::Application::YAML
```

Means, it can't find the definition of `YAML`. So, you need to require it in your file where you are using `YAML`.

In your `environment_variables.rb`, require the `yaml`:

```
require 'yaml'
```

This should fix your issue.